# ArrayIndex in XMLAttribute

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have an Xml which should be formatted like:

```
<name Segment1="infofor1" segment2="infofor2" Segment1_OtherInfo="SomethingElseFor1" Segment2_OtherInfo="SomethingElseFor2"/>
```

For the class I thought about the fallowing:

```
public class Name{
  public Segment[]Segment{get;set;}
}

public class Segment{
 [XmlAttribute("Segment???")]
  public string Segment{get;set;}
 [XmlAttribute("Segment???_OtherInfo")]
  public string SegmentOtherInfo{get;set;}
}
```

Generally speaking I want the index of the array into my Name of the XML Attribute. I Think that is totally nasty, but I cant change the xml, it is a requirement.
How can I achive that. The class I can change how I want.
Nice would be that the attributes are not written if they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the annotations in brackets will not be flexible enough for this (but I'd have to spend more time to find out). They rely on reflection and the `XMLSeralizer`, which means your code should represent somehow the XML model.

In my opinion, it is easier just to create `XElement`s and `XAttribute`s. With them, you can loop through your arrays, get the array's index (or to increase a counter) and add the necessary attributes with a suitable name.

Here is a well written example:
http://csharp-guide.blogspot.ch/2012/06/xattribute-class-is-used-along-with.html

Like this:

```
...
new XElement("name", new XAttribute("Segment" + counter, "infofor" + counter));
...
```

Comment: I want to use that additional to the XMLAttribute tags. How can I do that?